# Chef test shows nginx enabled and running service --status-all doesn't show it at all

Tags: nginx, testing, chef

I am trying to run a chef verify test and the test is showing nginx is enabled and running using this code:

```
describe service('nginx') do
  it { should be_enabled }
  it { should be_running }
end
```

It will not however show in the `/etc/nginx` directory. I can't find any mention of nginx in anywhere except my tests and the config files I put in place with my cookbook. Well the cookbook is one I have been given by a coworker.

Comment: Itd help to take a look at the cookbook/recipe(s)

Comment: If you don't see an `/etc/nginx`, the daemon may simply not be installed.  I don't know from Chef, but is there an `it {should be_installed }` you can add here, or something similar?

Comment: @ryekayo I can't post company cookbooks, good way to get fired.

Comment: Im not suggesting copying it word for word but really a snippet of would help

Comment: @DopeGhoti I added the `should be_installed` line and it passes just fine along with the ones above but when I test for nginx version no luck. Nor is it actually running, a `http get` request fails on localhost port 80

Adding `describe file ('/etc/nginx') do
  it { should_not exist }
end` ends with a failed test though.

Comment: @ryekayo The nginx cookbook I am working with is ~500 lines so any small snippet isn't really that helpful. I could put up 25 lines and it would be almost no help since a lot of the cookbook calls on other parts of it as it finishes things.